# for each call function with member function pointer and parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, pointer-to-member

I did a simple implementation of a template list:

```
template<typename T>List{
    [...]
private:
    class ListElement{
        ListElement * next;
        T* value;
    };
    ListElement *first, *last;
};
```

Now I would like to be able to write a "call for each" method, that takes a function pointer to a member function of the type T and calls that function for each item with the possibility to also pass arbitrary parameters to these function calls, like:

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
[...]
list.for_each_call(&Item::update, time_passed);
```

To update each item in the list with the time passed by calling it's `update(int time_passed)` method.

I can work around this by implementing this:

```
void List<T>::for_each_call(void (*func) (T*)){
    for(ListElement * current = this->first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
         func(current->value);
}
```

And every time I want to call a method on each stored value I call that function with something like this:

```
void call_update(Item* item){
    item->update(globally_set_update_value_before_calling_for_each);
}
```

But I already created 8 different globally defined "call_X" methods and this is starting to get annoying.

Can I implement what I described above? Lambda expressions are also something that would be neat to use here.

And yes I am trying to explicitly work around any std:: stuff and see how I might implement it on it's own without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement for "the possibility to also pass arbitrary parameters to these function calls" pretty much requires using a template, and parameter packs.

```
template<typename func_type, typename ...Args>
void for_each_call(func_type &&func, Args && ...args)
{
    for(ListElement * current = first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
         func(current->value, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the args... if you pass a lambda.

Comment: You don't, but this should work with a plain function pointer, too.

Comment: Also the solution uses std::forward , which is bad since I do not want to use std:: --- that is kind of the point of my self made exercise

Comment: Also how would I call this?

Comment: for_each_call(lambda/class/functionptr  [, any extra arguments>]*)

Comment: So I just tried this out and it works with: `(current->value->*call)(args ...);` also withput std::forward